# Sample size estimation

Tags: confidence-interval, sample-size, networks

I have $n$ data points that run in hundreds of millions. Ideally, I want to connect them with each other (based on a condition), run random walks on this interaction network, and make some inferences based on the random walks. This is intractable.

Naturally, I would like to subsample this data, connect with each other and run random walks. What should be this sub-sampling size so inferences made on the small network are reflected in some confidence with regards to the original network?

Comment: There are a lot of complexities about sampling from networks. For instance, do you sample nodes and drag along the edges, or do you sample edges and drag along the nodes? Do you alternate between the two? I’m interested in the responses this question might generate, but this might be an open question in network statistics.

Comment: Well, I can work with any if we know the answer to any one of the strategies. Right now, I don't have any clue on how to find this sample size :-(

Comment: @Dave, there could be a way to do it. We could first randomly subsample the original graph and find the node degrees. If we assume a model on the original graph, like Erdős–Rényi, we know the theoretical expected value and variance of such a model. For example, 

http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs485/2006sp/lecture%20notes/lecture1.pdf

We could use those equations to determine the number of nodes and the probability for generating the subsampled graphs.